# What problem led India to purchase Dassault Rafale?

Tags: su-30

The Su-30MKI is a contemporary, highly capable fighter aircraft. Since the 2000s, India has acquired a fleet of 260 such fighters.

What factors contributed to the Indian Air Force's assessment that these jets did not suffice for their operational needs?

What were the specific reasons behind India's procurement of 36 Dassault Rafale jets? Did practical military requirements or political considerations drive this acquisition?

Comment: Rafale is useful for putting on our carriers and for our navy

Comment: and India has a stock of Mirage 2000s, which I think they like quite a bit. And have weapons and other systems that won't fit on their Soviet designed aircraft.

Comment: Not wanting to be tied to Russia is probably also a factor

Comment: @MikeB, I'm not a diplomat or anyone qualified to speak on this and this site is not for politics but India has no issues keeping neutral relations with Russia and doesn't plan to break ties any soon.

Comment: @AadirajAnil, *Rafale is useful for putting on our carriers and for our navy* --- Faulty assumption! There were already 40 *Mig-29K*s purchased for that purpose. According to my analysis, the purchase of *Rafale* is a total political decision, most probably to give jobs to BJP allies like Anil Ambani, etc. However, I am here for a deeper and more reliable analysis.

Comment: @user366312, yeah, I know. There's a whole Wikipedia article on the controversy and it's not something that hasn't been covered in the news. Put this question on reddit and you will get the wildest answers that will cover the politics part too. You know, if you wanted to get into the detailed politics and talk about Anil Ambani, this isn't the greatest place...